# Karp hardness of a module in a graph

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, np-complete, np-hard, np

**DEFINITION**: A set of vertices $A\subseteq V$ in a graph $G(V,E)$ is called a **module** if it satisfies the following property:

> For every $v\in V\setminus A$, either $A\subseteq N(v)$ or $A\cap N(v)=\emptyset$, where $N(v)$ is the neighborhood of $v$.

**GRAPH-MODULE** problem:

> **Input**: An undirected graph $G(V,E)$ and a natural number $k$
>
> **Output**: **YES** if $G$ has a module $A\subseteq V$ with $|A|=k$, otherwise **NO**

What is the complexity of **GRAPH-MODULE** problem?